# Running server application behind router with No-IP DNS redirecting client?

Tags: python, redirect, static, ip

So i supose that i have a server application written in python

```
    import bottle
    import os
    from bottle import route, run

    @route('/', method='GET')
    def homepage():
        return 'Hello world!'

    @route('/events/:id', method='GET')
    def get_event(id):
        return dict(name = 'Event ' + str(id))

    bottle.debug(True) 
    run()
```

This will run at my current localhost 127.0.0.0:8080 a simple RESTful api. Now i will like
to write different client applications maybe in other programming languages that are able to connect to my RESTful api and use it.

Therefore i would like to have a static DNS or IP to which all my client applications know that they have to connect. Therefore this should not depend on which system i am running my server application.

The server application should always serve at the same static DNS or IP.

I tried registering a free domain redirect at www.NO-IP.com.

After i registered my hostname I have set it to redirect port 80 at my current external IP address, but unfortunately I am behind a router so the server application does not work.

Port forwarding is not an option, and will also defeat my purpose of being able to run the server application everywhere

Ideeas ?

Comment: upnp? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play

Comment: i don't see how can an UPnP can help me ? I said i need to be able to  run the server anywhere ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't have an answer, just the same issue. I had my domain registered with GoDaddy, but then got excited about No-IP's Port 80 redirect service and transferred to them. As it turns out, all it does is redirect to IP:Port and it can be masked but all of this prevents any server API from working correctly. Had I known this to be the case, I wouldn't have bothered paying the extra $30 to go from GoDaddy to No-IP, when GoDaddy is perfectly capable of the same thing with its redirect service, and even has two different masking options. I'm quite disappointed in No-IP.